# How to dynamically hide glyphs and legend items with Bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I am trying to implement checkboxes in bokeh where each checkbox should show/hide the line associated with it. I'm aware it's possible to achieve this with legends, but I want this effect to happen in two plots at the same time. Also, the legend should update as well. In the example below the checkboxes appear, but do nothing. I am clearly not grasping how to update de dataframe used as source. Thanks for any help.

```
from bokeh.io import show, curdoc
from bokeh.models import  HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, Legend
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Category10
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup
from bokeh.layouts import row
import pandas as pd

def update(atrr, old, new):
        lines_to_plot = [checkbox_group.labels[i] for i in checkbox_group.active]
        cols = ['x']
        for label in lines_to_plot:
            cols += [label + 'y']
            cols += [label]
        newdf = df0[cols] 
        source.data.update(ColumnDataSource(newdf))    

df0 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'Ay' : [1, 5, 3], 'A': [0.2, 0.1, 0.2], 'By' : [2, 4, 3], 'B':[0.1, 0.3, 0.2]})

columns = ['A', 'B']
checkbox_group = CheckboxGroup(labels=columns, active=[0, 1])

tools_to_show = 'box_zoom,save,hover,reset'
p = figure(plot_height =300, plot_width = 1200, 
           toolbar_location='above',
           tools=tools_to_show)

legend_it = []
color = Category10[10]
columns = ['A', 'B']
source = ColumnDataSource(df0)
for i, col in enumerate(columns):
    c = p.line('x', col, source=source, name=col, color=color[i])
    legend_it.append((col, [c]))


legend = Legend(items=legend_it, location=(5,114))#(0, -60))

p.add_layout(legend, 'right')

hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = [("Name","$name"), ("Aux", "@$name")]
hover.mode = 'mouse'

layout = row(p,checkbox_group)

checkbox_group.on_change('active', update)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Comment: You can toggle the renderers visibility instead, which is probably both less code as well as more performant. See the example in the GH repo: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/line_on_off.py

Comment: That does the trick almost perfectly. Could I hide the legend too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to manage `LegendItem` objects manually. Here is a complete example:

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis3
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, Legend, LegendItem

p = figure()
props = dict(line_width=4, line_alpha=0.7)
x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
l0 = p.line(x, np.sin(x), color=Viridis3[0], **props)
l1 = p.line(x, 4 * np.cos(x), color=Viridis3[1], **props)
l2 = p.line(x, np.tan(x), color=Viridis3[2], **props)

legend_items = [LegendItem(label="Line %d" % i, renderers=[r]) for i, r in enumerate([l0, l1, l2])]
p.add_layout(Legend(items=legend_items))

checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=["Line 0", "Line 1", "Line 2"], active=[0, 1, 2], width=100)

def update(attr, old, new):
    l0.visible = 0 in checkbox.active
    l1.visible = 1 in checkbox.active
    l2.visible = 2 in checkbox.active
    p.legend.items = [legend_items[i] for i in checkbox.active]

checkbox.on_change('active', update)

layout = row(checkbox, p)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Comment: How to get around this when using save/show:

WARNING:bokeh.embed.util:
You are generating standalone HTML/JS output, but trying to use real Python
callbacks (i.e. with on_change or on_event). This combination cannot work.

Only JavaScript callbacks may be used with standalone output. For more
information on JavaScript callbacks with Bokeh, see:

    https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html

Alternatively, to use real Python callbacks, a Bokeh server application may
be used. For more information on building and running Bokeh applications,

Comment: You have to run a Bokeh server to use real Python callbacks, there is absolutely no exception (browsers have no ability to run Python code at all). However, you could recast this specific example easily with a `CustomJS` that does the work in JavaScript code instead of the Python `update` function, and then also use `js_on_change` instead of `on_change`. There are lots of examples in the docs section on adding interactions.